# What is the difference between print and return in a function?

Tags: python, function

I have this function :

```
def sbo_extra_dwn(link, name):
    sbo_url_dwn = link + name + ".info"
    sbo_url_dwn = sbo_url_dwn.replace("repository", "slackbuilds")

    f = urllib2.urlopen(sbo_url_dwn)
    read_page = f.read()
    for line in read_page.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line[10:-1]
            if line.startswith('http'):
                    print line
```

This prints two links : http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/unvanquished/Assets/unvanquished_0.26.0.pk3 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/unvanquished/files/Assets/unvanquished_0.25.0.pk3

but if return a line don't take 2 links..... like this :

```
def sbo_extra_dwn(link, name):
    sbo_url_dwn = link + name + ".info"
    sbo_url_dwn = sbo_url_dwn.replace("repository", "slackbuilds")

    f = urllib2.urlopen(sbo_url_dwn)
    read_page = f.read()
    for line in read_page.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line[10:-1]
            if line.startswith('http'):
                    return line
```

the result is only one link:

How can return two more if necessary?

Comment: *** This print two links

Comment: Return them in a list

Comment: I think tuples would be better because of their immutability.

Comment: Either would work, I guess :)

Comment: But I used lists in my answer, I will edit it to include tuples

Comment: @Moe You can't use tuples here.. They're immutable. Except if you want to reassign the tuple each time, which would take more work than just appending to a list.

Comment: Yes, you can actually, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append your results to a list, and then return that list.

```
def sbo_extra_dwn(link, name):
    results = []
    sbo_url_dwn = link + name + ".info"
    sbo_url_dwn = sbo_url_dwn.replace("repository", "slackbuilds")

    f = urllib2.urlopen(sbo_url_dwn)
    read_page = f.read()
    for line in read_page.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line[10:-1]
            if line.startswith('http'):
                    results.append(line)
    return results
```

However, you might want to return a tuple because of their immutability (suggested by [@Moe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100799/moe)):

```
def sbo_extra_dwn(link, name):
    results = ()
    sbo_url_dwn = link + name + ".info"
    sbo_url_dwn = sbo_url_dwn.replace("repository", "slackbuilds")

    f = urllib2.urlopen(sbo_url_dwn)
    read_page = f.read()
    for line in read_page.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line[10:-1]
            if line.startswith('http'):
                    results = results+(line,)
    return results
```

In your 1<sup>st</sup> example, you are `print`ing the result. In the 2<sup>nd</sup> one, you are `return`ing. The `return` statement is pretty much like a `break`, only that it returns a value too. Thus, when you return the first value, it breaks from the function.

Comment: This answer ignores the important difference between the two examples in the question. Handing out code without explanation is bad for SO.

Comment: @msw added an explanation

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can append them to a list and return them, like @aj8uppal's answer. You can also use the `yield` keyword.

```
def sbo_extra_dwn(link, name):
    sbo_url_dwn = link + name + ".info"
    sbo_url_dwn = sbo_url_dwn.replace("repository", "slackbuilds")

    f = urllib2.urlopen(sbo_url_dwn)
    read_page = f.read()
    for line in read_page.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line[10:-1]
            if line.startswith('http'):
                    yield line
```

And then, you can use it like this:

```
lines = sbo_extra_dwn(my_link, my_name)
for l in lines:
    ....
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You've replaced the OP's `print`/`return` confusion with the notoriously more confusing `yield` without speaking to the underlying problem at all.

Comment: Hahahah. All right, i was just providing an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Your two code samples have two wildly different behaviors:

1. `print` which shows something on the standard output and allows the `for line` loop to continue and print other matches but returns `None` when execution falls off the end of `sbo_extra_dwn`
2. an almost identical function that does a `return line` on the first success thus terminating the entire `sho_extra_dwn` function. This **does** return a value, but only the first one found that matches the criteria.

Other answers here "gave you a fish" instead of showing you the mistake you made in your fishing technique. You need to understand the important difference between `print` and `return` and then the fix will make sense.

---

Compare these two bits of minimal code and how their behavior differs:

```
def printer():
    for c in 'user3634982':
        print c
```

How many lines are printed? What is the return value of `printer()`?

```
def returner():
    for c in 'user3634982':
        return c
```

How many lines are printed? What is the return value of `returner()`?

Comment: I'm flattered that someone thought I downvoted an answer but I didn't. In the exceedingly rare cases in which I do, I say so.